# Callback with a time

Tags: c#, callback, timer

I want to implement a method that callback a method at a precise time. We can have more than a method that can be called at the same time.

```
    public void CallmeBack(DateTime time, Action callback)
    {

    }
```

What's the best implementation in C# ?

My quick and dirty solution was to create a dictionary `Dictionary<DateTime, List<Action>>` and to make a timer every each (minute/second) and check the time (`DateTime.Now`) and a current time in the test mode.

The solution have to be "Safe" if the current machine time changed. So a simple solution like this couldn't work :

```
        Timer timer = new Timer((param) => {callback.Invoke();}, null,
            (long)(time - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
```

**Edit :**
Typical case where simple timer don't work is DST and manual time/date adjustment.
Plus, I just want the callback executed once not multiple times.

Comment: I know it is late, but have you solved this?  How precise do you need this to be...

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a cron library. There are many out there. Some have a lot of features and are a bit heavy. Here is a blog post about cron jobs and a library that I have used in production code.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/10/an-event-based-cron-scheduled-job-in-c/

Hope that helps get you started.

Bob

Comment: Just reread your post. Check the library and pay attention to your last requirement. It's been awhile and I have forgotten the internals.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it don't consider the time change. I'm taking a closer look the code to verify that. but at least, you get me started ;)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alternatives you may want to consider:

- You could use a **task scheduler** such as :http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/
- You could stick with a timer and listen for time changes using: [`SystemEvents.TimeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx). That event is triggered by user time changes. I assume you can handle predictable time changes (daylight saving etc.) when setting the timer in the first place. I'm not sure about NTP-related changes - you'd need to investigate that further.

Comment: I need to execute methods not process so the task scheduler can't resolve simply my problems.

Comment: For the event, I can eventually treat it.